# php change password ""sql xamp"" Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_query()

Tags: php

```
<post><?php
 $dbc=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die ('Failed'.mysqli_error());
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
   extract($_POST);
   if($old_password!="" && $password!="" && $confirm_pwd!="") :`enter code here`
    $user_id = '1';
    $old_pwd=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['old_password']));
    $pwd=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['password']));
    $c_pwd=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['confirm_pwd']));
    if($pwd == $c_pwd) :
       if($pwd!=$old_pwd) :
         $db_check=$dbc->mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$user_id' AND `password` ='$old_pwd'");
         $count=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$user_id' AND `password` ='$old_pwd'"));
         if($count==1) :
             $fetch=$db->mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '$pwd' WHERE `id`='$user_id'");
             $old_password=''; $password =''; $confirm_pwd = '';
             $msg_sucess = "Your new password update successfully.";
          else:
            $error = "The password you gave is incorrect.";
          endif;
        else :
          $error = "Old password new password same Please try again.";
        endif;
    else:
      $error = "New password and confirm password do not matched";
    endif;
   else :
     $error = "Please fil all the fields";
   endif;   
 endif;
   ?> <code>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: I advise you to read a mysqli manual first to learn __names of functions__.

Comment: I think you are missing $dbc-> at $count=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_query is not methot of the object. mysqli_query is just php function. 
Fix $db_check=$dbc->mysqli_query($dbc, ...); to     $db_check=$mysqli_query($dbc, ...);

If you want to use OOP, you must create mysqli object:
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

you can read about this here http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php.